# Non-System disk or disk error after installing Chrome OS Flex on HP laptop

Tags: google-chrome-os-flex

I thought I'd give **Google Chrome OS Flex** a go on my old **HP EliteBook 6930p** . It started off ok, and I can boot Chrome OS Flex off the created flash drive. The issue has arisen now when I actually did the install (over my Windows 10). I now get this when booting:

[image]

I've tried googling around, but I can't seem to find anything that helps! Any suggestions? I hope I haven't bricked my laptop.

The boot order of the drives is:

[image]

Comment: The first troubleshooting step is always checking the boot order (UEFI settings > Boot menu) and adjust accordingly. Have you?

Comment: @ChanganAuto thanks. I just did that, and it was set to the "upgrade" drive. I've changed it to "Notebook Hard Drive" (which is the primary drive/partition), and still no joy. I've included a photo of the order above

Comment: The information given in the previous comment assumed you had a UEFI based computer (~2012 or newer) but that ended up not being the case. Yours has the old BIOS. Although Google says nothing about it not working in old PCs (and even mentions that for some models users need to enable Legacy mode (AKA "BIOS" mode) the fact that all certified models are UEFI remains. The boot order for your is indeed determined by the drive order and the drive that had the priority during installation is the one that should have the bootloader.

Comment: @ChanganAuto thanks - so that means what exactly? :) It is indeed quite old. I did try making the main partion as the primary boot and then re-installing, but it still moans when trying to boot.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure it works but it should. If it were me I would 1) Boot a live session of Ubuntu or similar, then 2) use GParted to clean up the drive completely (Device menu, create new partition table, "mbr", apply). Then I would 1) Assure the boot order in BIOS is set so the target drive has the first priority and 2) Boot the ChromeOS installer and install fresh.

Comment: If it complains after all the aforementioned steps then it's fairly safe to assume it won't work in that machine. Try a normal yet "light" Linux desktop distro.

Comment: @ChanganAuto thanks, will see if I can get that to work :)